# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

добрый день, не могу понять почему я не могу добавить в параметры процедуры второе значение, выдает ошибку

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another
>   SqlParameterCollection

```
        ValueSQLDataPC.FlagBegin = true;
        ResultPCInfo = GetMethod.GetPCData(ID, IP);
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.CommandText = "sp_CheckIndex";
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter[] ParameterArray = new SqlParameter[2];
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.Parameters.Add("@CheckCode", SqlDbType.Int, 342);
        SqlParameter ReturnResult = new SqlParameter("@ResultSearch", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        ReturnResult.Value = "";
        ReturnResult.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.Parameters.Add(ReturnResult);
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ResultCheck = Convert.ToString(ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.Parameters["@ResultSearch"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый объект `SqlParameter` можно использовать только один раз. В вашем коде повторного использования одного и того же `SqlParameter` нет, так что воспользуйтесь отладчиком и найдите конкретную строчку. Скорее всего это будет строка вида

```
someCommand.Parameters.Add(someParameter);
```

где тот же самый объект `someParameter` уже раньше был передан в другой вызов типа `someOtherCommand.Parameters.Add(someParameter)`.
Уберите повторное использование этого `someParameter`, и ошибка пропадет.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но в статьях microsoft не видел что этот параметр используется единожды да и многие примеры показывает схожую конструкция, а как тогда можно использовать набор переменных с параметрами для процедуры, пробовал массив тоже самое

Comment: ни разу не видел повторного использования параметра в msdn. можно ссылку? может я не вполне однозначно выразился - у вас проблема не в том коде, который вы привели в вопросе. можете указать конкретную строчку, на которой падает?

Comment: я имею в виду в описании, статей пример (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044214/adding-more-number-of-parameters-to-sqlparameter-class) строка с ошибкой ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.Parameters.Add(ReturnResult);

Comment: в статье по ссылке каждый параметр используется один раз. вы точно привели весь код? потому что в том виде, в котором он у вас в вопросе - он падать не должен. Может быть проблема в повторном использовании `SendCommand` - создавайте ее заново - или в особенностях реализации `ValueDataConnect`.

Comment: Мне так не показалось 4 ответ, вот к примеру ещё http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54638/extending-database-factory-class-to-use-auditing-class, можете привести пример как можно отправить массив переменных с параметрами, много вариантов перепробовал но результата нет, вторая встречавшийся ошибка это отправка первой переменной без отправки второй

Comment: Вы немного не поняли - один и тот же параметр можно добавлять в разные коллекции - например, в разные массивы типа `SqlParameter[]`. Но после добавления его именно в коллекцию именно типа `SqlParameterCollection` он привязывается к ней, и попытка добавить его в другую `SqlParameterCollection` он выбрасывает ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался

Answer (score -1):

4 часа потратил на это

ParameterArray[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

спасибо PashaPash